# need to enable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a small form. I want enable submit button when all the all the radio button is selected.

below is my code html

```
<form action="#" id="form1" method="post">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h3>Here’s what I want:<strong class="result1"></strong></h3>
                        <div>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="Cash Back rewards" name="want" id="01"  /><label for="01">Cash Back rewards</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="Travel rewards" name="want" id="02" /><label for="02">Travel rewards</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="Gas rewards" name="want" id="03" /><label for="03">Gas rewards</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="Shopping rewards" name="want" id="04" /><label for="04">Shopping rewards</label></span>
                    </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <h3>Here’s my credit story: <strong class="result2"></strong></h3>
                        <div>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="I’m new to credit" name="story" id="05" /><label for="05">I’m new to credit</label></span>
                            <span><input type="radio" value="I pay my bills on time" name="story" id="06" /><label for="06">I pay my bills on time</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="I’ve had credit issues in the past" name="07" id="issues" /><label id="07">I’ve had credit issues in the past</label></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <h3>Here’s what I carry:</h3>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="I have a credit card with a good record" name="carry" id="08" /><label for="08">I have a credit card with a good record</label></span>
                        <span><input type="radio" value="I don’t have a credit card with a good record" name="carry" id="09" /><label for="09">I don’t have a credit card with a good record</label></span>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" value="" name="" class="find" />
                </form>
```

i am weak in javascript please advise me.

one more thing if li is not fix it will generate dynamically, so what i will have to do. basically every li is one quetion and radio button is option. so the question will be generate dynamically it can be any no. its not fix

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':radio').on('change', function(e) {
  var len = $(':radio:checked').length;
  if( len === 3 ) {
     $('input[type=submit].find').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U8WaH/36/)**

Comment: **bold** one more thing if li is not fix it will generate dynamically, so what i will have to do

Comment: `3` could be replaced with `$('#form1 li').length` if number of elements is not fixed. Note that the last radiobutton of the second `li` doesn't have the same `name` attribute as the others. This answer assumes - reasonably - that this is in error.

Answer (score 0):

There 4 groups of radio buttons in your markup, you can check if the length of selcted radio buttons are equal to the length of radio groups, and if that is true, enable the submit button, try the following:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio]', function(){
   if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length == 4) {
       $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false)
   } 
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5xYXr/)

Please note that the third element in the `story` group has a different name attribute.

```
<span><input type="radio" value="I’m new to credit" name="story" id="05" /><label for="05">I’m new to credit</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" value="I pay my bills on time" name="story" id="06" /><label for="06">I pay my bills on time</label></span>
<span><input type="radio" value="I’ve had credit issues in the past" name="07" id="issues" /><label id="07">I’ve had credit issues in the past</label></span>
                                                 --------------------------^
```

Comment: **bold** one more thing if li is not fix it will generate dynamically, so what i will have to do.

basically every li is one quetion and radio button is option. so the question will be generate dynamically it can be any no. its not fix

Comment: @VikasSharma Sorry you should post another question for that. but wait i'll update my answer.

Comment: @VikasSharma you should delegate the event, try the updated one.

Comment: can't you help me here just let me know how to make it dynamic

Comment: @VikasSharma I can, but you should post another question for that.

Comment: i have post another question by the title "need to enable submit button on select of radio button" please answer on that

Comment: @VikasSharma I have answered your question, did you check the updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Or again:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function(){
    if(
         $('input[name=want]').is(':checked') &&
         $('input[name=story]').is(':checked') &&
         $('input[name=carry]').is(':checked')
     ){
         $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false)
     }
});
```